# Powershell command to see what Exchange calendars a user has access to

Tags: permissions, powershell, exchange, calendar

I'm trying to find a PowerShell command that would show me what calendars a certain user has permissions to.

I can use `Get-MailboxFolderPermission -identity “User:\Calendar”` to find what permissions are set on that specific mailbox but what I need is sort of the reverse.

I have Exchange 2010.

Comment: Try something such as `Get-MailboxFolderPermission domain\username:\calendar  | Select FolderName, user, AccessRights`. I don't have an Exchange 2010 to run against but look over https://practical365.com/exchange-server/list-users-access-exchange-mailboxes/ when you get a chance to for something you may find helpful.

Answer (score 0):

The below command works for me in my environment:

```
Get-Mailbox | % { Get-MailboxFolderPermission (($_.PrimarySmtpAddress.ToString())+”:\Calendar”) -User *user1* -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue} | select Identity,User,AccessRights
```

It will list all mailboxes on whose Calendar the user1 has additional permission.

Refer to: http://www.michev.info/Blog/Post/1516/quickly-list-all-mailboxes-to-which-a-particular-user-has-access

Comment: This did not work for me (Exchange 2010). The command executed without errors but nothing was returned, despite the fact I have users that should be found.

Comment: This only works for primary calendars, not secondary calendars.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this script.
https://o365reports.com/2021/11/02/get-calendar-permissions-report-for-office365-mailboxes-powershell/

Sample Output:
[image]

Additionally, the script can generate 6 different calendar permission report based on the parameter you pass while executing the script.

Comment: Sorry for the downvote. Please post the script here.  You can still leave the link to it. Links can disappear making your answer useless in the future.  I will upvote it then.